# re.findall with or logic

Tags: python, regex

I am getting a list of 2 items when using an '|' in regex findall, which one of them is blank

I tried changing the regex format a few times but nothing worked. This is what I have so far after trying different variations:

example filenames:

```
231_HELLO_01.jpg
01_HELLO_WORLD.jpg
HELLO_01_WORLD.jpg
```

Code

```
    pattern = '_(\d{2}).?|^(\d{2})_'
    finddupe = re.findall(pattern, filename)
```

output looks like this

```
[('01', '')]
[('02', '')]
[('01', '')]
[('02', '')]
[('01', '')]
[('02', '')]
[('03', '')]
[('04', '')]
[('05', '')]
[('06', '')]
[('07', '')]
[]
```

I am just looking to get the number without the empty strings and lists.

Looking for:

```
01
02
01
03
04
```

Comment: Maybe `finddupe = ''.join(*finddupe)`?

Comment: makes no difference actually

Comment: Can you give a real example? What is a real value for the variable filename?

Comment: please see edits

@brunoluvizotto

Comment: Which numbers do you want to get?
In this one, for example: "231_HELLO_01.jpg" -> 231 or 01?

Comment: the 01 @brunoluvizotto

Comment: Instead of needing special cases for beginning of string etc., maybe just `.split()` the string on `_` and/or `.` and check which parts match the 2-digit pattern?

Comment: Karl Knechtel's suggestion is also pretty valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove `.?` in one of the alternatives as it does not impact matching and concat group values upon a match:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('^(\d{2})_|_(\d{2})')
m = pattern.search('12_text')
finddupe = ""
if m:
    finddupe = f"{m.group(1) or ''}{m.group(2) or ''}"
    # finddupe = "{}{}".format(m.group(1) or '', m.group(2) or '') # for Python versions not supporting interpolation
print(finddupe)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Pij974)

I see you need to get the first match in each string, thus, there is no point using `re.findall` that returns all, multiple matches, `re.search` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can't tell if it is going to cover all your data, but you can try the following:

```
names = ["231_HELLO_01.jpg", "01_HELLO_WORLD.jpg", "HELLO_01_WORLD.jpg"]

result = re.findall("[^\d](\d{2})[^\d]", ' '.join(names))
```

The value of result after running it is:

```
>>> result
['01', '01', '01']
```